# Redirect SKNode SkAction direction while touching

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

While a player is touching, the code below is suppose to move a node to the `MaxX`. Once they hit that point it is suppose to redirect the node's movement towards the `MinX` and vice versus.

As it stands right now, I can only move the player in once direction and it is ignoring the `movePlayer()` logic.

**Action Declarations**

```
 var moveRightTest:Bool = true;
 var moveLeftTest:Bool = false;

 let moveRight = SKAction.moveByX(1000, y: 0, duration: 2);
 let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-1000, y: 0, duration: 2);
```

**Inside the GameScene:**

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    movePlayer();
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    stopPlayer();
}

func movePlayer() {
    if(moveRightTest == true) {
        if(player.position.x <= CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)) {
            player.runAction(moveRight);
        } else  {
            moveRightTest = false;
            moveLeftTest = true;
        }
    }

    else if(moveLeftTest == true) {
        if(player.position.x >= CGRectGetMinX(self.frame)) {
            player.runAction(moveLeft);
        } else {
            moveLeftTest = false;
            moveRightTest = true;
        }
    }
}

func stopPlayer() {
    player.removeAllActions();
}
```

*Note: I subbed out some vars with ints/floats to remove the calculation from the code in order to present. Its not related to the issue.* Im also just learning Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now your function `movePlayer` is performed only once when you're calling it, so the player comes to the right edge and stops. You need to repeat it after each run the following steps. To do this, you can use `runAction` with `completion` like this:

```
isRight: Bool = true

let moveRight = SKAction.moveToX(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame), duration: 2)
let moveLeft = SKAction.moveToX(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame), duration: 2)

func movePlayer() {
    if isRight {
        player.runAction(moveRight, completion: { () -> Void in
            isRight = false
            self.movePlayer()
        })
    } else {
        player.runAction(moveLeft, completion: { () -> Void in
            isRight = true
            self.movePlayer()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This has helped me a lot. Im not sure that I'm heading in the right direction tho. This is suppose to be the movement for the main player. Would this be the way to do it or is there another method that would suit better than SKaction?

Comment: @Ray I do not quite understand what you mean. Is it possible to move the main character using SKAction? If so then of course you can. You can use `moveTo(location: CGPoint, duration: NSTimeInterva)` method and animate movement to any point on your scene. Or you mean something else?

Comment: Basically what I was asking would SKAction be the best use case in my scenario or is their another method that would better suit my needs. Ive noticed some side effects using SKAction such as the animation slowing down when en route to boundary. This occurs after the TouchEnded and TouchBegan transition. Should I use sequences? Sorry for all the questions. Im making this project to better understand swift.

Comment: @Ray To do this, you can try to dynamically change the `speed` of the `SKAction` animation with timer for example, I never did it, but you can try and see what happens. But in general, yes, most complex animations are made of a series of simple with group it with `sequences`, or you can  `group` to create simultaneous effects, such as an object and moves and changes its color or transparency.

Comment: You may have look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/80586/make-line-drawing-game-sprite-kit-swift. I think that a time based movement will fit your needs better than an action based movement. If not you should remove the current running action with `removeActionForKey` and then start a new action.

Comment: @Pierre, I saw that. I didn't think it would fit as touch starts and stops the characters movement along the X regardless of touch position. The velocity should remain the same. Thanks for the recommendation